# controller business logic design iOS

Tags: ios, uitableview, model-view-controller, software-design

I have a question about controller business logic design in iOS,

when I have a viewController which could be reused for multiple pages, and some different elements such like navigationItem title, API call, different cell height or types, what is a proper way to do this?

What I'm doing now is add enumeration for it, something like

```
enum(controllerType) {
    typeA
    typeB
}
```

And for each method need to config different elements, I do something like this

```
switch type {
    case typeA:
    //Changes for type A
    case typeB:
    //Changes for type B
}
```

Specially sometimes for a tableViewController, need add config another kind of cell in some type, so tableView delegate and dataSource will have a heavy business logic

Lightly optimize like separate delegate/dataSource in another file or category/extension, of separate the business logic into another file kind like 'viewModel' and use method in viewModel instead of heavy logic in viewController, but it will still have big methods in viewModel, so what is the proper way to design the reused controller?

Answer (score 0):

You can set a string property (e.g. isComingFrom) from which controller you are coming from and put checking of that string in your common view controller that is reutilising. Hope it will help you.